# Raphael.js : how to unset Element's attr?

Tags: raphael

I have a link set to Element:

```
element.attr({href: 'http://google.com'});
```

Now I want to delete a link. I'm trying:

```
element.attr({href: false});
element.attr({href: null});
element.attr({href: ''});
```

But none of them works.

Even

```
delete element.attrs.href;
```

doesn't help.

How can I unset element's attribute?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you should be aware that (using Raphael API,) `.attr()` does not affect the underlying DOM element, but merely attaches a property to the Raphael object. if you wish to address the node's `href` attribute you should call `element.node.href` or `element.node.setAttribute('href', ...)`.

Comment: you can add your reply as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be aware that (using Raphaël API,) `.attr()` does not affect the underlying DOM element, but merely attaches a property to the Raphaël object.

if you wish to address the actual node's `href` attribute you should either use:

```js
element.node.href = 'http://google.com';
```

or:

```js
element.node.setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');
```

Check out ['Element.node' on the Raphaël's documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.node).